# How to use a specific tag/version with composer and a private git repository?

Tags: composer-php

I've got some packages host on the Gitlab of my company. I want to request a specific version of these packages but each time I try, composer download the latest commit of the master branch.

composer.json :

```
{
   "name" : "MyProject",
   "require" : {
      "user/project" : "v0.5.0"
   },
   "type" : "project",
   "repositories" : [
      {
         "url" : "git@gitlab.XXXX.fr:user/project.git",
         "type" : "vcs"
      }
   ],
   "config" : {
      "vendor-dir" : "private/class"
   }
}
```

The structure of the repository of my package :

- tag v0.5.0 : commit dd6ed3c8...
- commit X,Y,Z
- tag v0.7.0 : commit 15293ac6...
- last commit f15600a1...

When I execute "composer install" :

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> Analyzed 69 packages to resolve dependencies
>
> Analyzed 67 rules to resolve dependencies
>
> - Installing user/project (dev-master f15600a)
>
>   Cloning f15600a1

It downloads the last commit only.

How can I configure the composer.json file of my project to use a specific tag ?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

**How to require a specific Git tag?**

Change the version requirement to `dev-master`, followed by a hash `#` and the  Git tag name, e.g. `v0.5.0`, like so:

```
"require": {
    "vendor/package": "dev-master#v0.5.0"
}
```

**How to require a specific Git commit?**

Change the version requirement to `dev-master`, followed by a hash `#` and the  Git commit reference, e.g. `dd6ed3c8`, like so:

```
"require": {
    "vendor/package": "dev-master#dd6ed3c8"
}
```

Referencing: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links

---

**Define your own package and set version and reference**

An alternative to working with repositories of `"type": "vcs"` is to define a custom package `"type": "package"` inside repositories and work with a reference.

The reference is either a Git commit hash, or a tag or branch name, like `origin/master`.

This will tie the `version` to a specific commit `reference`, in this case dd6ed3c8.

```
"repositories": [
  # ...
  {
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
      "name": "vendor/package",
      "version": "v0.5.0",
      "source": {
        "url": "git@gitlab.server.com:vendor/project.git",
        "type": "git",
        "reference": "dd6ed3c8"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I already try this and each time it downloads the last commit. Not the requested tag/commit

Comment: I don't know why type vcs doesn't work out for you. I've added an example for defining your own package inside repositories. This allows to set a version and a reference.

Comment: I tried your last proposition and still the same result. It clones the whole repository (and uses the last commit)

I don't understand why this happens. Maybe I need to use something similar to packagist...

Comment: It seems that Gitlab repositories are a problem for Composer and that it will only use Github and Bitbucket's APIs to download the zip archive.While in Gitlab,it will not pick the reference up on a checkout, nor will it fetch a dist(archive of the source) - it will just git clone.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/wemakecustom/gitlab-composer Its a branch/tag indexer for Gitlab repositories. Untested.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll give a try to the branch/tag indexer :)

Comment: In my case, `dev-master#v0.5.0` didn't work but `v0.5.0` worked.

Answer (score 31):

Pull by **git tag**:

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://gitlab.xxx.com/some/repo.git"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "some/repo": "1.0.2"
  }
}
```

Pull by **latest git commit**:

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://gitlab.xxx.com/some/repo.git"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "some/repo": "dev-master"
  }
}
```

Pull by **specific git commit**:

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://gitlab.xxx.com/some/repo.git"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "some/repo": "dev-master#68696f39"
  }
}
```

**Add repository** via **Composer Cli** and pull **latest git commit**:

```
composer config repositories.repo git https://gitlab.xxx.com/some/repo.git
composer require "some/repo:dev-master"
composer update
```

Answer (score 11):

To require a specific branch you can also just `dev-`branchname like this:

```
"require": {
    "user/project" : "dev-my-branch"
},
```

Comment: Enough people saying `dev-master` made enough sense, but thank you for clarifying this easily with the whole `dev-` bit... :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a specific version hash after '#', for example:

```
require": {
    "user/project": "dev-master#31454f258f10329ae7c48763eb898a75c39e0a9f"
}
```

see: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you can use the version hash for the purpose.