# Composer fetches last commit ignoring tag specification

Tags: git, composer-php, drupal-8

This is what I do in my composer.json:

```
require {
    ...
    "myvendor/mypackage": "1.0-alpha1"
    ...
}
```

where `1.0-alpha1` is a tag name. But after I launch `composer update` it fetches the **latest** commit, ignoring the fact that tag `1.0-alpha1` points to the previous commit. I searched the Internet for possible causes and found this discussion on SO: [How to use a specific tag/version with composer and a private git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784809/how-to-use-a-specific-tag-version-with-composer-and-a-private-git-repository) 
I should say, that neither worked for me. E.g. I tried adding `dev-master#` prefix, but this didn't help.

Here is my full `composer.json`, @see `myvendor` substring:
https://gist.github.com/OnkelTem/75922ad74da5f5973c28ffb1155cfd40

It is created using https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using

```
require {
    ...
    "myvendor/mypackage": "^1.0"
    ...
}
```

That will install "at least 1.0" (following semver) which includes alpha, beta, RC since you have

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
```

Comment: Thank you for the contribution, but I've discovered that my question is INVALID. The reason was completely different - I was using incorrect composer.json. But that was not so clear - I'm not that stupid :) @See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645274/the-same-file-on-host-and-inside-container-is-different-it-is-not-in-sync-with