# How do I change timezone in a docker container?

Tags: docker, timezone, devops

I am running docker container for my development stack which I pulled from docker-hub, the image is created for a different timezone than where my application is supposed to be deployed.

How do I change timezone in a docker container?

I tried to change the timezone config within the container by running

```
echo "Africa/Lusaka" > /etc/timezone
```

and restarted the container but I still get the same timezone.

Comment: hi @LinPy I used postgresql:10

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can override as suggest by [LinPy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57607433) during the run stage, but if you want to set it in your Dockerfile you can use ENV as tzdata is already there in your base image.

```
FROM postgres:10
ENV TZ="Africa/Lusaka"
RUN date
```

Build

`docker build -t dbtest .`

RUN

`docker run -it dbtest -c "date"`

Now you can verify on DB side by running

`show timezone;`

You will see `Central Africa Time` in both container and Postgres.

In the alpine base image, the environment variable will not work. You will need to run

```
 RUN ls /usr/share/zoneinfo && \
cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Brussels /etc/localtime && \
echo "Africa/Lusaka" >  /etc/timezone && \
```

Comment: Note that `tzdata` package has to be installed. Or `/usr/share/zoneinfo` may not even exist. This is the case for me for a Ubuntu docker container. I have to install `tzdata` first.

Comment: Yup agree @jdhao, but its already exist in the Postgres image base on alpine https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/f1e039c4ebd8e4691af65dfd6cf280df126039aa/10/alpine/Dockerfile

Comment: To get a list of valid values to use for TZ, refer to this site: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Answer (score 72):

There's a few ways to do it .

1. You can declare the time zone directly as an environment variable in the docker compose file

> ```
>    environment:
>       - TZ=Asia/Singapore
>       - DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
> ```

2. You can map the container's time zone and local time files to use that of the host machine in the docker compose file

> ```
> volumes:
> - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
> - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
> ```

I personally prefer to use the second method, in this way , all of my containers will have the same time configuration as my host machine

Comment: And if you want to do this at run time (adding it here just for completeness)
`docker run -it --name=my-ubuntu --rm -v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro my-ubuntu:1`

Comment: Is there a way to change it in an existing container?

Comment: Mouunting timezone and localtime isn't a good approach. Individual file mounts might not always follow the file on the host. Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45645383

Comment: _"Individual file mounts might not always follow the file on the host"_. Interesting. Good to know, but not in this case -- my timezone is fixed when my box is first up and running. I.e., I will never flip their contents back and force. So, indeed, I _also_ prefer _"to use the second method, in this way , all of my containers will have the same time configuration as my host machine"_, despite whether the tzdata package has been installed or not in the container. I.e., the top selected answer is not working for me as the tzdata package is not installed in my container, yet this method works.

Answer (score 47):

Simply change the /etc/localtime to the time zone in the /usr/share/zoneinfo directory.

follow these steps:

first log into bash of your container:

```
docker exec -u 0 -it mycontainer bash
```

then remove the symbolic link file (/etc/localtime):

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/localtime
```

Identify the timezone you want to configure and create the symbolic link for it:

For instance, I would like to set Asia/Tehran timezone:

```
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tehran /etc/localtime
```

Now verify it by:

```
date
```

and the output would be your timezone:

```
Sat Jan 30 14:22:17 +0330 2021
```

Comment: fantastic, helpful answer.  Also, interesting use of -u 0 which I hadn't seen before and made it so I could rm the original /etc/localtime.  If you don't use that option then you don't have rights to do that.  Thanks again.

Comment: I would add that you need to install tzdata before, as if the package is not installed, the directory `/usr/share/zoneinfo` will not exist.

Answer (score 29):

the best way is to use `ENV` in your run stage

```
-e TZ=Africa/Lusaka
```

and make sure that the package `tzdata` is present in the `Container`

Answer (score 5):

A simpler method would be to add an env var to your deployment:

```
env:
  - name: TZ
    value: "Europe/London"
```

(kubernetes deployment yaml)

Answer (score 4):

If you have `TZ` env set correctly and you still get the wrong time, make sure the `tzdata` system dependency is installed.

Answer (score 1):

This question was about a postgres base, mine was about an Alpine base, but based on the Alpine Wiki, what I can glean of best practice means my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM alpine:3.14
RUN apk add --no-cache alpine-conf && \
    setup-timezone -z Europe/London
```

https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_setup_scripts#setup-timezone

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who are using --env-file. add

```bash
# .env
TZ=Asia/Shanghai
```

To .env file, and it will get the time zone you want.

Answer (score 1):

For France, for a docker container, in the docker-compose.yml, i tested successfully:

In the volume section i added these 2 entries:

```
volumes:
- /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:fr
- /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:fr
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
ls /usr/share/zoneinfo/
```

to show all zone

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a docker file to update the time of your region in a docker container, I used Asia/Kathmandu TZ,

```
 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-alpine
    
    RUN apk update && \
        apk add --no-cache curl nano lsof jq unzip dos2unix aws-cli tzdata
    
    ENV TZ=Asia/Kathmandu
    RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
    
    # Set the timezone to Kathmandu
    RUN ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kathmandu /etc/localtime && \
        echo "Asia/Kathmandu NST" > /etc/timezone
```