# How to mount a Linux system time file?

Tags: linux, docker, virtual-machine

I am working on a docker container. For which I need to change the time zone and time of the system. I was able to change the time zone and time of the system.

But how do I locate and mount the Linux system time file before I start the docker container?

Comment: There's environment variables that control this, like [`TZ`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change timezone in a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57607381/how-do-i-change-timezone-in-a-docker-container)

Comment: I was able to change the time zone and time. I need help to mount the linux system time file.

Comment: What are you trying to do that doesn't work?  Are there some specific commands you're running?  (Are you trying to break out of the container to change the host system's clock?)