# Requesting specific tagged version for locally developed composer package

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am developing a package for a Laravel project on my local machine. I have also spun up a Laravel app so I can manually test the package. My package is located at `/home/me/packages/me/my-package` and a commit (git) has been tagged with '0.1'.

I want to be able to switch between tagged versions and use specific versions in different projects but having issues.

In my main apps composer file, I am requiring the package like so:

```
...
"require" : {
    "me/my-package" : "0.1"
}
...

"repositories" : [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "/home/me/packages/me/my-package"
    }
]
```

This results in an error:

```
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires me/my-package 0.1, found me/my-package[dev-main] but it does not match the constraint.
```

I have also tried:

```
"require" : {
    "me/my-package" : "dev-main#0.1"
}
```

(This was an idea taken from [How to use a specific tag/version with composer and a private git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784809/how-to-use-a-specific-tag-version-with-composer-and-a-private-git-repository)). This goes through without any errors but:

```
$ composer show | grep me/my-package

me/my-package dev-main     My Package
```

What is the correct way install a specific version of a package when developing it locally?

Comment: I think your are damn close to have this right already, just the type of repository. I added an answer for clarity and with some links). /E: and let me know if it does not fully work, there are some edge cases, but for those feedback is necessary, so just comment on the answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the *only* thing why you hit this message is that you have `"type": "path"` and not `"type": "vcs"`.

This is that Composer will only refer *one version and only one version **dev-main***. The reason is:

> If the package [path repository] is a local VCS repository, the version may be inferred by the branch or tag that is currently checked out. ([ref](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path))

You have the `main` branch checked out at `/home/me/packages/me/my-package` (`/home/me/packages/me/my-package/.git/HEAD` content is `ref: refs/heads/main` and `/home/me/packages/me/my-package/.git/refs/heads/main` points to the git revision) and composer will only take that one.

You should have no problem to make that change from *path* to *vcs* given:

- You already have a (git) repository at `/home/me/packages/me/my-package` (looks so by your question)
- You know the absolute path on your local system to that repository (again, looks so by your question: `/home/me/packages/me/my-package`).

Given these two points, Composer is able to obtain the VCS tagged versions from that path. So basically only the change of the `"type"`:

```
"repositories" : [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "/home/me/packages/me/my-package"
    }
]
```

Just take care that `"url"` contains the absolute path (and there is a git repository at that place). Likely already all set in your case, just saying.

Git is very prominent that's why I mentioned it here, for other types of VCS Composer also has options at hand. The details - also for git etc. - are available here:

- [VCS - Repositories (getcomposer.org)](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs)

Comment: Thank you! Obvious really now that it has been pointed out. Didn't try this as assumed `vcs` should be external. If I specify `path`, composer is not looking for a repo - just the location of some files. `vcs` ensures it is looking for a repo and can read the versions/branches etc not just what is checked out. Thanks again!